# NSDictonary to JSONString returns null

Tags: ios, json

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"creditCardId" : self.creditCardId,
                            @"receiptDescription" : self.receiptDescription,
                            @"currency" : self.currency,
                            @"chargeAmount" : self.chargeAmount,
                            @"recipientFacebookAccount" : self.recipientFacebookAccount,
                            @"recipientName" : self.recipientName,
                            @"recipientMobilePhoneNumber" : self.recipientPhoneNumber,
                            @"sendByFacebook" : [self.sendByFacebook boolValue] == YES ? @"true" : @"false",
                            @"sendBySMS" : [self.sendBySms boolValue] == YES ? @"true" : @"false",
                            @"message" : self.message,
                            @"recipientFacebookImageUrl" : self.recipientFacebookImageUrl,
                            @"recipientFacebookUserId" : self.recipientFacebookUserId,
                            @"senderFacebookImageUrl" : self.senderFacebookImageUrl };   
NSDictionary *wrapperDict = @{ @"type" : self.messageName,
                                       @"deviceId" : [DSSettings sharedSettings].deviceId,
                                       @"payload" : [dict JSONString] };
```

[dict JSONString] returns null. same types of conversation works well in other cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Since JSONString is a 3rd-party category, make sure it's actually installed.

2) NSLog your dictionary after creation and make sure it's correct.

3) Use NSJSONSerialization, specifying a valid `error` parameter, and then, if the call returns nil, log the `error` parameter to find out specifically what's wrong.

Comment: Yes [dict JSONString] returns (null) however I checked three times for NSDictonary log and no parameters has null value.  I am wondering because everything was working perfect three days back. Is there any other easy way to convert data into JSO format?

Comment: So, try #3.  Even if you're wed to JSONString for some reason, you can still use NSJSONSerialization for debugging.

Comment: Also, pull the `[dict JSONString]` call out into a separate statement where you can examine the result easily.  There's no efficiency gain in doing it the way you have it.

Comment: Dict: {
    chargeAmount = 1000;
    creditCardId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    currency = CAD;
    message = "Enjoy a little something on me!\n\nCheers, Skai";
    receiptDescription = drink;
    recipientFacebookAccount = iamviren;
    recipientFacebookImageUrl = "http://graph.facebook.com/1588762806/picture/type=large";
    recipientFacebookUserId = 1588762806;
    recipientMobilePhoneNumber = "";
    recipientName = "Viren Gujariya";
    sendByFacebook = true;
    sendBySMS = false;
    senderFacebookImageUrl = "http://graph.facebook.com/547570538/picture/type=large";
}

Comment: above is dictionary log. what do you see that can be wrong?

Comment: Are you sure those are all NSStrings and NSNumbers, and some aren't objects which *look* like a string or number when logged?  (#3 would suss this out for you.)

Comment: Well accroding to #3 exception is: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (NSURL)

Comment: Are your two URL values NSStrings or NSURLs?

Comment: Well I converted all parameters into NSString and it worked. Does it right way?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you don't have nil values in your dictionary declaration, from apple docs about objective c literals:

> Neither keys nor values can have the value nil in containers. If the
>   compiler can prove that a key or value is nil at compile time, then a
>   warning will be emitted. Otherwise, a runtime error will occur.

Comment: Yes [dict JSONString] returns (null) however I checked three times for NSDictonary log and no parameters has null value.  I am wondering because everything was working perfect three days back. Is there any other easy way to convert data into JSO format?

Comment: You can't put nil values into a dictionary or array to begin with.

Comment: I am not putting nil values. I checked log. every parameter has values.